Updating Lon, Lat fields in QField using current phone coordinates, not the existing point coordinate
I have an existing point layer created in in my QField project that has two fields: stage_lat, stage_lon.  I would like to update those lat/long coordinates with the coordinates obtained from my phone not the geometry of the point that is already created.  The point can't move and I already have the coordinates for that. These coordinates would represent a set of coordinates for a location that could be hundreds of meters away or kilometers.
I've tried the x($geometry) & y($geometry) OR $x & $y + apply default values on update, but that doesn't record my phones position:  

You can use specific qfield variables for that like @position_coordinate. the following expression will transform the position_coordinate into the current project crs and get the x-value:
x(transform(@position_coordinate, 'EPSG:4326', @project_crs ))


I don't get a value when I make a change to the form.

you will need to test it on your mobile, in QGIS desktop there will be no value, because the varaibles are only used in qfield
